# i18next-fs-backend/esm/readFile.js:135:17 Error resolving commonjs request

Tags: next.js13, next-i18next

I have an error in the terminal while dev server is run.
[resolve]
node_modules/i18next-fs-backend/esm/readFile.js
node_modules/i18next-fs-backend/esm/readFile.js:135:17  Error resolving commonjs request

I build ssg, and my code in the lib/getStatic.js looks like this:

````
import i18nextConfig from '../next-i18next.config';

  export const getI18nPaths = () =>
    i18nextConfig.i18n.locales.map((lng) => ({
      params: {
        locale: lng
      }
    }))

  export const getStaticPaths = () => ({
    fallback: false,
    paths: getI18nPaths()
  })

  export async function getI18nProps(ctx, ns = ['common']) {
    const locale = ctx?.params?.locale
    let props = {
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, ns))
    }
    return props
  }

  export function makeStaticProps(ns = {}) {
    return async function getStaticProps(ctx) {
      return {
        props: await getI18nProps(ctx, ns)
      }
    }
  }```

What I did wrong? Please help..

I'm getting the redirects in loop, but it may be doesn't depending on the error above. I read an answers in the issue https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next/issues/935#issuecomment-775085693 but didn't understand how can I use it in my case
````